# how to update session timeout in web.config file form C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, web-config

I want to update session timeout from C# code

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc" 
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20"/>
</system.web>
```

I use `Session.Timeout=50` and that works fine but I want to change the value in Web.Config file.

After completing action file should be update like

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState 
          mode="InProc" 
          cookieless="false" 
          timeout="50"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use session.timeout=50 in your code. it won't effect to your config file. Instead of trying to change web.config how about the Global.asax file's Session_Start method and set Session.TimeOut to whatever you want.

More info :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

add these lines in global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Context.Session != null)
            {
                if (Context.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    Context.Session.Timeout = 50;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the way we can change connection string from c# code

`var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
configuration.Save();`

Comment: yes it's possible. you can change any config parameters in web.config from your code.

Comment: can you please write the code for changing session timeout?
I was failed to get `sessionState` from `system.web` section

Comment: as you know when you change config file. your web application will be recycled and you will lose current session.  that way is not proper. I suggest that set the timeout value when your application is starting which is global.asax

Comment: I found an Exception by `Session.Timeout = 50;` in Global.asax file

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Session state is not available in this context.